# How to check for nil inside extension

Tags: swift

Following code

```
extension String {

    func isValidEmail() -> Bool {
        if self == nil { return false }
```

Gives me error `Value of type 'String' can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed`

Is it possible to somehow check for nil here?

Comment: That makes no sense. You cannot call the method on a `nil` String.

Comment: Ah, sure! As @Fogmeister has pointed, Swift does not have "nil messaging".

Comment: Even in Objective-C `self` cannot not be `nil` inside the method. "nil messaging" means that the message is  *discarded*  if the receiver is `nil`. – A similar mechanism in Swift is optional chaining: `someOptionalString?.isValidEmail()`.

Comment: @MartinR that's true. I hadn't thought of that. Updated my answer slightly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checking for `nil` there is not required.

That function is an instance function on `String`.

It can only ever be run on an instance of `String`.

Secondly Swift does not have "nil messaging" like Objective-C so the String instance that the function is called on **HAS** to be not nil. Even in Objective-C this would still not matter as the function would not run if called on a nil String.

So, the message is correct, `Value of type "String" can never be nil`.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if your string is empty as:

```
var myString : String?

if myString.isEmpty {
   // do whatever you want ..
}
```

That's has more sense..

Answer (score 0):

Recall that in Swift, values of type `String` can *never* be `nil`; if you wanted a nillable value, you'd have to declare it `String?`.

So no, there is no way to check if a `String` variable is set to `nil`, *because it can't*.